# Django Form Wizard - Setting default value for text input field

Tags: python, django, django-forms, modelform, django-formwizard

I'm tooling a widget for a datefield in my ModelForm wizard. I'd like to achieve this with a widget, so I can keep all the nice validation features of Django's ModelForm.

I am modeling my widget after this portion of `django.forms.extras.widgets.SelectDateWidget`:

```
def create_select(self, name, field, value, val, choices, none_value):
    if 'id' in self.attrs:
        id_ = self.attrs['id']
    else:
        id_ = 'id_%s' % name
    choices.insert(0, none_value)
    local_attrs = self.build_attrs(id=field % id_)
    s = Select(choices=choices)
    select_html = s.render(field % name, val, local_attrs)
    return select_html
```

Notice that I can add to the list of list choices by affecting the `choices` variable which changes the final html rendering via `django.forms.widgets import Select`

However, I would prefer to simply allow users to type in the year and date, instead of fumbling with dropdown menus. So for those, I have converted the widget to utilize this:

```
def create_input(self, name, field, value, val, none_value):
    if 'id' in self.attrs:
        id_ = self.attrs['id']
    else:
        id_ = 'id+%s' % name
    local_attrs = self.build_attrs(id=field % id_)
    inp = TextInput()
    select_html = inp.render(field % name, val, local_attrs)
    return select_html
```

It's working great, but it would be cool to set a default value here. Is this possible from the widget or the form?:

```
class EventRegistrationForm4(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['start_date', 'start_time', 'end_time']
        this_year = datetime.date.today().year
        widgets = {
            'start_date': InputDateWidget(),
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it simply in the widget, just test, if val is empty and if it is, then put in your default value like this:

```
def create_input(self, name, field, value, val, none_value):
    if 'id' in self.attrs:
        id_ = self.attrs['id']
    else:
        id_ = 'id+%s' % name
    local_attrs = self.build_attrs(id=field % id_)
    inp = TextInput()
    if val == None or val == '': 
        val = '2015-11-29' # or use datetime.now(), or compute another good default
    select_html = inp.render(field % name, val, local_attrs)
    return select_html
```